# SyntaxError ao descompactar elementos de iteráveis

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
line = 'nobody:*:-2:-2:Unprivileged User:/var/empty:usr/bin/false'
uname, *fields, homedir, sh=line.split(':')
print fields
```

Estava fazendo estudos no Python e me debarei com a linha assim, ao tentar compilar recebo a seguinte mensagem

```
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

por que isso está acontecendo? estou utilizando o cookbook

Comment: `Missing parentheses`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No python 3 o print é usado com parêntesis:

```
print("A resposta é:", 2*2)
```

Comment: Bacana, estava acostumado com o 2.7x